# Formating curl request correctly for Microsoft Graph API

Tags: curl, microsoft-graph-api

**EDIT: I believe I got it working my update is below**

I am trying to retrieve a token from Microsoft graph api using curl. I have an `application ID`, `Tenant ID`, `client secret value`, and `client secret secret id` from the app registration portal so I assume I have everything I need to get a token.

I am at section 4: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

In there documentation it shows an example like this:

```
// Line breaks are for legibility only.

POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

I tried that format and it failed for me:

```
curl POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/MYTENANTNUMBER/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1 Host:login.microsoftonline.com Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded client_id=ENTERCLIENTIDHERE&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=ENTERCLIENTSECRETEHERE&grant_type=client_credentials
```

I also tried a couple of different methods but everyone of them failed. This was the closes as this one gave me no errors but it didn't respond back with anything either:

```
curl -H "Host:login.microsoftonline.com" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "client_id=ENTERCLIENTIDHERE&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=ENTERCLIENTSECRETEHERE&grant_type=client_credentials" "https://login.microsoftonline.com/MYTENANTNUMBER/oauth2/v2.0/token%20HTTP/1.1"
```

If anyone has any ideas let me know. Thanks

**UPDATE - I Think I got it working but I wanted someone to double check for my code to make sure**
I think this got me what I needed:

```
curl -n -v -i -H "Host:login.microsoftonline.com" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "client_id=ENTERCLIENTIDHERE&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=ENTERCLIENTSECRETEHERE&grant_type=client_credentials" "https://login.microsoftonline.com/MYTENANTNUMBER/oauth2/v2.0/token"
```

I had to take out the `HTTP/1.1` at the end of the url. In microsoft's documentation they used that in the url so I am not sure why it works without it.
This is the reply I get which **I THINK** is what I need:

```
{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599,"ext_expires_in":3599,"access_token":"SOMESUPERLONGTOKENTHINGYTHATIAMNOTGOINGTOPUTINHERE"}*
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that would be

```
curl -d 'client_id'='535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865' \
-d 'scope'='https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' \
-d 'client_secret'='qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX' \
-d 'grant_type'='client_credentials' \
 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token'
```

curl will take care of the rest, the request curl actually sends will be something like

```
$ nc -l 9999
POST /https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9999
User-Agent: curl/7.77.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 157
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX&grant_type=client_credentials
```

(i recorded that with netcat, changing the url to `http://localhost:9999/https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token`)

fwiw the command was generated with the php code

```php
<?php

$str='client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX&grant_type=client_credentials';
parse_str($str,$res);
$cmd="curl ";
foreach($res as $key=>$val){
    $cmd.="-d ".escapeshellarg($key)."=".escapeshellarg($val)." \\\n";
}
echo $cmd;
```

when adding POST data with `-d`, curl will automatically change the request to a POST request (away from the default GET request), and add the `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header, and add the actual post data, and encode the data, and typically you should *not* add the `Host: login.microsoftonline.com`-header manually, curl will generate that header for you. (in some special cases, such as when debugging DNS issues, generating the header manually is useful, but not in your case, unless you're a login.microsoftonline.com sysadmin debugging a DNS issue, which obviously isn't the case )